# How to float an image next to text with a gap inbetween

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line up my company_name div next to my logo div. I am also trying to make a gab in between the two. I understand that both divs need to have width and need to be floated left but I am unsure if I need a clear:both or if I am just completely off.

This what I want the end result to be
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHG02.jpg

HTML

```
   <header id="main_header">
       <div class="inside clearfix">
                <div id="flat">
                    <div id="logo"><a href=""><img src="img/relson_logo.png" alt="Relson Gracie Academia De Jiu Jitsu"></a></div>

                    <div id= "company_name"> <h1> Relson Gracie 
                        Jiu-Jitsu Athens </h1> <h2> 507 Richland Ave. Suite 202 Athens, Ohio 45701 (614) 976-9867 </h2>
                         </div>

                </div>
                    <nav id="desktop">
                        <ul id="desktop_ul">
                            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </nav><!-- end of nav#global -->
                </div>
            </header><!-- end of header#main_header -->
```

CSS

```
#main_header    {

background:#4f63a6;
}

#company_name{
float: left;
margin-right: 70%;
width: auto;



}

#logo img  {

float: left;
margin-right: 25%;
max-width: 30%;
height: auto;

}


#company_name h1{
font-weight: 200;
color: #fff;
line-height: 1em;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 20px;    
}

#company_name h2{
font-weight: 200;
color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```css
#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 25%; /* adjust it */
  margin-right: 5%; /* adjust it */
}

#company_name {
  float: left;
  width: 70%; /* adjust it */
}

.clearfix:after, #flat:after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content: " ";
}
```

Comment: If I might make a suggestion, some description of what the CSS does might help the questioner.